# to generate client code from httpsnippet(npm)

Tags: npm, code-generation, kong

I am not able to get headers in the output while generating the client code

```
const snippet = new HTTPSnippet({
method: 'GET',
url: 'http://mockbin.com/request',
headers: {
'content-type': 'Application/json',
}
});

const options = { indent: '\t' };
const output = snippet.convert('shell', 'curl', options);
console.log(output);
```

output

```
[Error [HARError]: validation failed] {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'type',
      dataPath: '.headers',
      schemaPath: '#/properties/headers/type',
      params: { type: 'array' },
      message: 'should be array'
    }
  ]
}
```

expected: - headers should be the part of the curl rather than this error

Answer (score 0):

The validation message says that `headers` should be an array.

---

[HAR Docs](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/) (found in [httpsnippet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/httpsnippet));

> `<headers>`
>
> This object contains list of all headers (used in `<request>` and `<response>` objects).
>
> ```
> "headers": [
>     {
>         "name": "Accept-Encoding",
>         "value": "gzip,deflate",
>         "comment": ""
>     },
>     {
>         "name": "Accept-Language",
>         "value": "en-us,en;q=0.5",
>         "comment": ""
>     }
> ]
> ```

Comment: Please open a new question.